# How to get data out of ember objects

Tags: javascript, ember.js, kendo-grid

I'm fairly new to ember and I'd like to know whats the fastest way to extract the data out of ember objects. I've loaded my model with a very large amount of records using `this.store.find('modelName`);` in my route.

I created a component on my view using `{{kendo-ui.kendo-table descriptor=tableDescriptor data=model}}`. My controller defined other arguments to be passed to my component (`descriptor`).

In my `components.js` I'm' getting the `data` passed over by using

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

didInsertElement: function() {
  var columns = this.get('descriptor.columns'); // this is right
  var model = this.get('data')['content'];      // this returns the objects of the model
  var height = this.get('descriptor.height');   // this is ok too
  Ember.$('#kendo-table').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: model,
      pageSize: 100
    },
    height: height,
    scrollable: {
        virtual: true
    },
    groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    columns: columns
  });
  }
});
```

On the line `var model = this.get('data')['content'];`, this gives me an Array of Ember Classes. Inside each class, there is a `_data` object that holds the value of the actual class.

The easiest solutions is to just loop through and extract the `_data` but that is no good for larger model array. Is there a quick way to extract all the `_data` from my array of ember objects?

Comment: Just `this.get('data')`

Comment: @Artych You mean `this.get('data').get('data')` since first level is referring to the array of classes and the second level is referring to... each object in the array?

Comment: May be I do not understand you... 1) `this.store.find('modelName')` is promise that resolved as RecordArray 2) you could get it in route controller as `model` 3) you pass `model` to component as `data` => 4) so my answer is  `this.get('data')` in component

Comment: Oh I see, I have a model using `this.store.find('modelName')`, it is binded to my controller. My controller has an attribute named `model` I believe this includes `this.controller` and the model its binded to. I then pass the `model` to my component. Now I need to get the data that came from `this.store.find('modelName').get('data')`, should I inject my component with the `store` as components don't come with it?

Comment: Misunderstanding between us. Once more, please. 1)  Let I have model `person` (with 1 attr `name`). In router `this.store.find('person')` is promise. In controller it is already **resolved** as RecordArray, for example first element name: `this.get('model').get('firstObject').get('name')`. 2) you pass `model` to component as `data` => my answer is `this.get('data')` in component

Comment: I guess, may be you are asking how to transform Ember.RecordArray to array of hashes?

Comment: I'm not so clear with the ember terminology, is a hash the object identifier? I would like to get the full object (with all attributes) that was in my store, and since the RecordArray has many of them (thanks for that tip!), I will need an array of `person`s

Comment: The RecordArray that I currently possess is an object wrapper to my `person`s data, it has all sorts of getter and setter methods, prototypes that is not apart of my original `person` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `getProperties` method. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_getProperties

To get the values of multiple properties at once, call getProperties with a list of strings or an array:

```
 record.getProperties('firstName', 'lastName', 'zipCode');
 // { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', zipCode: '10011' }
```

You could define computed property `dataArray`:

```
dataArray: function() {
  return this.get('data').map( function(item) {
     return item.getProperties('id', ... ); // your list of properties
  });
}.property('data.[]'),

didInsertElement: function() {
  //...
  Ember.$('#kendo-table').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: this.get('dataArray'),
      //...
    },
    // ...
   });
}
```

**UPDATE:**
for records (`DS.Model`) you could use `toJSON` method. Use DS.JSONSerializer to get the JSON representation of a record.

`toJSON` takes an optional hash as a parameter, currently supported options are:

- `includeId: true` if the record's ID should be included in the JSON representation.

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_toJSON

Comment: see update, please, toJSON({includeId: true}) would be good to you.